# How to get a selected list of documents on a Firebase list?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list on Firebase

```
list: {
  -firebasepushid1: {...},
  -firebasepushid2: {...},
  -firebasepushid3: {...},
  -firebasepushid4: {...},
  -firebasepushid5: {...},
  -firebasepushid6: {...},
  ...
}
```

I know I can get the whole list with `db.ref("list/")` or a especific document `db.ref("list/-firebasepushid1")`.

What If I want to get 3 especific documents?

I think 2 ways but they would cause overload on the server I guess:

1. Making a loop for the 3 documents separately
2. Get the whole list and seek on the client

It would be ideal to do this with a single query to the server. You have some way?

Comment: Add the tag of the language in which you are coding

Comment: Javascript.....

Comment: Would you know those 3 specific id beforehand? Or you want selection of 3 id nodes in each iteration

Comment: @Dravidian beforehand.

Comment: Looping over the IDs and requesting the documents separately is not significantly slower than requesting them with a single `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` query on Firebase. This is because Firebase pipelines the requests/responses. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Its ok for me to set all the "db.ref().on()" separately?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Resuming: getting a new data query in Firebase doesn't mean opening a new pipeline, yes?

Comment: That's correct. It all goes over a single socket. So the overhead of setting up the connection is only occurred on startup (or upon a reconnect) and all requests are then pipelined over that connection.